# React: Show loading spinner while images load

Tags: reactjs, image, spinner, loading

I have a React app which makes a call in `useEffect` to my API which returns a list of URLs to use as imy image srcs.

I am using `react-loader-spinner` to show a loading spinner component while my images load.

I have a `loading` variable in `useState` to determine whether the images are loading.

I can not figure out how to stop showing the loading spinner and show my images once they have all loaded.

Here is my code:

**Photos.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react'
import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner';
import { getAllImages } from '../../services/media.service';
import Photo from '../common/Photo';

const Photos = () => {
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);
      getAllImages()
        .then(results => {
          setPhotos(results.data)
          console.log(results.data)
        })
        .catch(err =>{
          console.log(err)
        })
  }, [])

  const handleLoading = () => {
    setLoading(false)
  }

  return ( 
    <Fragment>
      <div className="photos">
          { loading ? 
            <Fragment>
              <Loader
                height="100"    
                width="100"
              />
              <div>Loading Joe's life...</div>
            </Fragment>
            :
            photos.map((photo, index) => (
                index !== photos.length - 1 ? 
                <Photo src={photo.src} key={photo.id} /> :
                <Photo src={photo.src} key={photo.id} handleLoad={handleLoading}/>
            ))
          }
      </div>
    </Fragment>
   );
}

export default Photos;
```

**Photo.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

import './Photo.css';

const Photo = (props) => {
  return ( 
    <div className="photo">
      <img src={props.src} alt={props.alt} onLoad={props.handleLoad}/>
      <div className="caption">
        Photo caption
      </div>
    </div>
   );
}

export default Photo;
```

I tried using `onLoad` for my last item but it will never get called because `loading` is never set back to false due to the spinner still being shown.

Some help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: seems like the [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) should be enough to run a callback and set the state?

Comment: @Sagivb.g - it is never reached

Comment: Well we would need to see the `Photo` implementation in order to try to understand why. BTW, why are you invoking it `handleLoading(false)` ?

Comment: It is not because of the Photo component, it is because the `loading` never changes to false.

Comment: @Sagivb.g - ive added my Photo component

Comment: it seems that you are not passing it though. You are invoking a function (which has no return expression) so basically you are passing `undefined`

Comment: @Sagivb.g - see my edits. I don't need a return expression. It is just to trigger a state update. But that function never even gets called anyway

Comment: Try setting `[loading]` on your `useEffect`, otherwise it's just going to set reset on next render, alternatively why not just set the default to true, and remove `setLoading` in your `useEffect` as your causing a re-render for no reason.

Comment: Also some heads up here, assuming the last image in your map will be the last image to be loaded is a tad naive.. :)

Comment: If someone could enlighten me with an answer with some code examples please for a solution then id be grateful

Comment: @Keith - and yeah I thought that, it's a solution i saw elsewhere on SO. Safe to assume the image with the largest file size would most likely be the last to load??

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The reason why onLoad was never called, is because you never had the images in the DOM, so instead of conditionally rendering, conditionally set the display property to none & block.

Below is a simple example of how you could wait for all images to load.

> Safe to assume the image with the largest file size would most likely be the last to load

Most certainly not!!, the time it takes for an image to load is not always down to size, caching, or server load can effect these.

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useRef} = React;

const urls = [
  "https://placeimg.com/100/100/1" ,
  "https://placeimg.com/100/100/2" ,
  "https://placeimg.com/100/100/3"
];

function Test() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const counter = useRef(0);
  const imageLoaded = () => {
    counter.current += 1;
    if (counter.current >= urls.length) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
  return <React.Fragment>
    <div style={{display: loading ? "block" : "none"}}>
       Loading images,
    </div>
    <div style={{display: loading ? "none" : "block"}}>
      {urls.map(url => 
        <img 
          key={url}
          src={url}
          onLoad={imageLoaded}/>)}
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
  <Test/>
</React.Fragment>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: Just another question, is it possible to solve this using conditional rendering?

Comment: @blueprintchris  You could, but it's a bit more work.  What you could do is use `fetch` api to load images. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @blueprintchris Sure. Try: { loading && <div>Loading images</div> }

Comment: Your answer helped me to implement skeleton while loading an image. Thanks.

Comment: beautiful 

Answer (score 5):

just create and component like this and load anywhere that you want to using image :

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function MyImage({src, width, size}) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    return (
    <div style={
        {
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            width: width?width:"100%",
        }
    } >
    <img src={src} style={
        {
            display: loading?"none":"block",
            width:"100%",
            animation: "fadeIn 0.5s",
        }
    } onLoad={(e)=>{setLoading(false)}}></img>
    <div className="spinner" style={{
        display: loading?"block":"none",
        fontSize: size?size:"24px"
    }} ></div>
</div>)}
```

you just need define a css class as "spinner" for spinner and an animation as "fadeIn" for image  if you want more ui effect.
usage :

```
<MyImage src="link/to/image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

How are they? Thank you for helping. I have it as the Keith solutions, but it still doesn't call the onLoad function. The only way for it to work and trigger onLoad is that instead of display, use visibility over the img parent tag. I would like it to work with display prop

```
<div style={{visibility: loading ? "hidden" : "visible"}}>
  {urls.map(url => 
    <img 
      key={url}
      src={url}
      onLoad={imageLoaded}/>)}
</div>
```