# Infinite loader

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, loader

I fetch image urls from an API

```
 const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
 const loadedImagesCounter = useRef(0);
 const imagesCounter = useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImages = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await request({
          url: 'http://localhost:5000/image/get-images',
          params: { category }
        });
        setImages(response);
        imagesCounter.current = response.length;
      } catch {}
    };

    fetchImages();
  }, [setImages, category]);
```

Every image has `onLoad` that increments `loadedImagesCounter`

```
{images.map((img, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={index} className="admin-images__item">
      <img
        onLoad={() => {
          loadedImagesCounter.current++;
        }}
        className="admin-images__img"
        src={`http://localhost:5000/${img}`}
      />
    </li>
  );
})}
```

Why does `<Spinner />` component go infinitely?

```
{loadedImagesCounter.current !== imagesCounter.current && <Spinner />}
```

Comment: useRef has additional `current` property. The proper way to update ref is: `loadedImagesCounter.current++` and then check `loadedImagesCounter.current !== imagesCounter....`

Comment: @demkovych I do it in `onLoad` on `img`

Comment: and whats a values of your loadedImagesCounter and imagesCounter variables? Are they incrementing?

Comment: @demkovych Sorry, miss one thing, updated

Comment: the problem is that ref methods doesn't call re-render. You need to work with state instead. Here is some example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902522/react-show-loading-spinner-while-images-load