# Load image quickly on URL change dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

In NextJS,

I have an image component (next/image), which renders the URL which is in prop, but the URL is dynamic.
This means if the user clicks on `ONE` the state changes to 1 so the URL changes, similarly for `TWO`, `THREE`, `FOUR`, and `FIVE`.

But the issue is, on state change the URL also changes but on UI it's reflecting after some time (load time).
I need the image immediately load or at least disappear the previous image on URL change and load the whole image.

I don't want to render all image at first and display only one base on state because the page already exceeds DOM size.

Any technique to solve this issue?

Comment: Either you will need to preload the images, or you display spinners while the images load. I believe you already have plenty of answers to the first on stackoverflow like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript. [`<link rel="preload" as="image">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload) seems promising

Comment: Hi @Andy Need to try spinner, but can't preload all images because it reduces the page speed.
Any clue when to show spinner in react perspective?

Comment: Why would it reduce page speed? It’s a resource hint, created for performance purposes. The browser will wait to download it until it’s idle.

Comment: If you want to go with a spinner anyway, or a solution that combines both, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902522/react-show-loading-spinner-while-images-load

Comment: Oh ok, I thought preload will cause an increase in initial load time. Thanks for your help.