# React render after effects from loading spinner

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a React application with a loading spinner that goes away when an API call finishes. I have the loading spinner set up to render in my index file like this:

```
  if (isFinishedLoading === false) {
    return (
      <LoadingSpinner/>
    );
  }

  return (
     {rest of code}
  )
```

Where `isFinishedLoading` is false as set by useState.  I call the needed API like this in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    apiGET()
}, [])
```

and I call `setIsFinishedLoading(true)` inside of `apiGET()`.

However, there is always a split second where the page is not fully rendered, it looks like some divs appear before others and the site flickers a little bit, it doesn't look like a fully rendered site.

My question is: is this just a fact of using React that it will take a half second for the page to fully render?  Or am I implementing my loading spinner in the wrong way?

I've tried a few things:

1. Putting my `setIsFinishedLoading(true)` in a setTimeout(),
2. Adding an additional loading flag to wait until all images are loaded like this: [React: Show loading spinner while images load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902522/react-show-loading-spinner-while-images-load)

Ideally, I'd be able to call something like img "onLoad" for divs, but that sounds a lot like useEffect() anyway. For what it's worth, the application is in Gatsby.

Comment: there is some time where the js needs to be downloaded and parsed. try add the same spinner inside your app div (which is called by reactDOM). so it will wait for the js download too

Comment: @Sysix Since it's gatsby, I don't have an app.js file or div, just `index.js`

Comment: Try to make```isFinishedLoading= false``` as default and your ```LoadingSpinner``` component is default UI to render; When state of ```isFinishedLoading``` change render the out put UI.

Answer (score 0):

Because of some of your Dom need the data whose got in async HTTP apiGet. They will appear later than other Dom whose not need api.

If you want to show both of them at the same time ,you may need to promote your Loading and state to a parent's component to control all Dom's display while data is got from apiGet .